# Java hangman. How to create multiple buttons and actionlisteners?

Tags: java, user-interface, button, actionlistener

I am trying to create a hangman game with a button for each letter of the alphabet. I have done this the hard way, using absolute positioning and multiple actionlisteners. Is there any way I can do both with a for loop?

Also, how can I implement my hangman using a polymorphic array? The way I have it now, I will use an if statement for each of the limbs. I'd wrather create the man on his own panel, then set the visibility for each limg to true as the use fails at guessing.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class HangmanGui extends JFrame{
    private JLabel headerLabel;
    private JPanel man;
    private Graphics gobj;

    private JButton aButton ;
    private JButton bButton ;
    private JButton cButton ;
    private  JButton dButton ;
    private  JButton eButton ;
    private  JButton fButton ;
    private  JButton gButton ;
    private  JButton hButton ;
    private  JButton iButton ;
    private  JButton jButton ;
    private  JButton kButton ;
    private  JButton lButton ;
    private  JButton mButton ;
    private  JButton nButton ;
    private  JButton oButton ;
    private  JButton pButton ;
    private  JButton qButton ;
    private  JButton rButton ;
    private  JButton sButton ;
    private  JButton tButton ;
    private  JButton uButton ;
    private  JButton vButton ;
    private  JButton wButton ;
    private  JButton xButton ;
    private  JButton yButton ;
    private  JButton zButton ;
    private  JButton newWButton ;
    private JButton showWButton ;
    private  JButton quitButton ;
    private  JButton startButton ;

    private JLabel blankWord;

    private JLabel titleWord;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel hangman;
    private FlowLayout layout;
    private Container container;



    /*  
    public static void main (String[] args){
        GUITest gui = new GUITest();

        gui.setSize(800,900);
        gui.setVisible(true);

    }
 */ 
     //
    //   public GUITest()
   //  {



   //  }



    public HangmanGui(){
        buildGui();

    }





    public void buildGui(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        Font lblFont= new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30); 
         JLabel[] uscore = new JLabel[15];

        Man man = new Man();

        titleWord = new JLabel("A Game of Hangman.");
        titleWord.setBounds(260,10,500,150);
        titleWord.setFont(lblFont);


        add(titleWord);
    //  add(blankWord);
        //frame.add(man);
        this.add(man);
        man.setBounds(100,100,400,400);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();


        panel.setBounds(6, 232, 400, 400);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);



        layout = new FlowLayout();
         container = getContentPane();
         setLayout(null);


         aButton = new JButton("A");

         add(aButton);
         aButton.setBounds(30, 520, 50, 29);
        aButton.addActionListener(
                 new ActionListener()
                 {
                 @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {

                    }
                 }
                 );



           bButton = new JButton("B");
         add(bButton);
        bButton.setBounds(80, 520, 50, 29);
        bButton.addActionListener(
                 new ActionListener()
                 {
                 @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                    {

                    }
                 }
                 );
        cButton = new JButton("C");
     add(cButton);
    cButton.setBounds(130, 520, 50, 29);
    cButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    dButton = new JButton("D");
     add(dButton);
     dButton.setBounds(180, 520, 50, 29);
    dButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       eButton = new JButton("E");
     add(eButton);
    eButton.setBounds(230, 520, 50, 29);
    eButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    fButton = new JButton("F");
     add(fButton);
     fButton.setBounds(280, 520, 50, 29);
    fButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       gButton = new JButton("G");
     add(gButton);
    gButton.setBounds(330, 520, 50, 29);
    gButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    hButton = new JButton("H");
     add(hButton);
     hButton.setBounds(380, 520, 50, 29);
    hButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       iButton = new JButton("I");
     add(iButton);
    iButton.setBounds(430, 520, 50, 29);
    iButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    jButton = new JButton("J");
     add(jButton);
     jButton.setBounds(480, 520, 50, 29);
    jButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       kButton = new JButton("K");
     add(kButton);
    kButton.setBounds(530, 520, 50, 29);
    kButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    lButton = new JButton("L");
     add(lButton);
     lButton.setBounds(580, 520, 50, 29);
    lButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       mButton = new JButton("M");
     add(mButton);
    mButton.setBounds(630, 520, 50, 29);
    mButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    nButton = new JButton("N");
     add(nButton);
     nButton.setBounds(680, 520, 50, 29);
    nButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       oButton = new JButton("O");
     add(oButton);
    oButton.setBounds(30, 550, 50, 29);
    oButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    pButton = new JButton("P");
     add(pButton);
     pButton.setBounds(80, 550, 50, 29);
    pButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       qButton = new JButton("Q");
     add(qButton);
    qButton.setBounds(130, 550, 50, 29);
    qButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    rButton = new JButton("R");
     add(rButton);
     rButton.setBounds(180, 550, 50, 29);
    rButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       sButton = new JButton("S");
     add(sButton);
    sButton.setBounds(230, 550, 50, 29);
    sButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    tButton = new JButton("T");
     add(tButton);
     tButton.setBounds(280, 550, 50, 29);
    tButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       uButton = new JButton("U");
     add(uButton);
    uButton.setBounds(330, 550, 50, 29);
    uButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    vButton = new JButton("V");
     add(vButton);
     vButton.setBounds(380, 550, 50, 29);
    vButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       wButton = new JButton("W");
     add(wButton);
     wButton.setBounds(430, 550, 50, 29);
    wButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    xButton = new JButton("X");
     add(xButton);
     xButton.setBounds(480, 550, 50, 29);
    xButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
       yButton = new JButton("Y");
     add(yButton);
     yButton.setBounds(530, 550, 50, 29);
    yButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
    zButton = new JButton("Z");
     add(zButton);
     zButton.setBounds(580, 550, 50, 29);
    zButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );

     startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
     add(startButton);
     startButton.setBounds(100, 700, 120, 29);
    startButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );

     newWButton = new JButton("New Word");
     add(newWButton);
     newWButton.setBounds(250, 700, 120, 29);
    newWButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );
     showWButton = new JButton("Show Word");
     add(showWButton);
     showWButton.setBounds(400, 700, 120, 29);
    showWButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );

     quitButton = new JButton("Quit Game");
     add(quitButton);
     quitButton.setBounds(550, 700, 120, 29);
    quitButton.addActionListener(
             new ActionListener()
             {
             @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {

                }
             }
             );



}
```

}

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Man extends JPanel {

     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g ){
                super.paintComponent(g);


       //gallows
           g.fillRect(10, 250, 150, 20);
           g.fillRect(40,70,10,200);
           g.fillRect(40,70,60,10);
           g.setColor(Color.yellow);
           g.fillRect(95,70,5,25);
          //head
           g.setColor(Color.black);
           g.drawOval(82,95,30,30);

           //body
           g.drawLine(97,125,97,150);
          //left leg
           g.drawLine(97,150,117,183);
           //right leg
          g.drawLine(97,150,77,183);
           // right arm
           g.drawLine(97,125,117,135);
           //left arm
           g.drawLine(97,125,77,135);




}
```

}

Comment: `"how can I implement my hangman using a polymorphic array?"` -- what is a "polymorphic array"? I've never heard of this term and have no clue as to what you mean. Why not just use an array?? Say an array of JButton -- `JButton[]`? What happened when you tried this?

Comment: Sorry. It's a term my professor throws around. A polymorphic array, according to my professor, stores the different states of an object. Like, bark, meow or roar for a Speak superclass.

Comment: Each `JButton` instance carries it's own state, so a simple array should be more then enough

Comment: Yes, but what would that look like? Would I use a for loop?

Comment: Yes, use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
// create a JPanel to hold the buttons that uses a GridLayout with 3 rows
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, ));
for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
{
    wButton = new JButton('A' + i);
    buttonPanel.add(wButton);
    // wButton.setBounds(30 + i * 50, 550, 50, 29); // avoid this
    wButton.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {

            }
        }
    );
}
// here add the buttonPanel to the main GUI
```

To break this down:

1) We use a for loop to go thru the 26 letters of the alphabet.

2) We create a button with the title being the letter. Because characters are actually just integers, adding 1 to 'A' yields 'B'. So, we can use 'A'+i as a little trick. Also, you could use an array of all the letters instead and do something like letter[i] there.

3) Avoid use of setBounds but rather use the layout managers to more easily and simply place and size the buttons.

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this, it's just something to get you on the right track.

Comment: setBounds? Come on now, none of that please. If you're going to recommend to newbies, make it a worthwhile helpful recommendation, such as to place the JButtons in a GridLayout using JPanel.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just recreated the OP's code using a for loop, as they asked. I did not comment on how "correct" this was.

Comment: Then I'm calling it out its lack correctness in your post. Please improve the recommendation.

Comment: Well, it did something. Unfortunately, the button has taken up the entire screen.

Comment: I took the liberty of improving your answer thereby allowing me to remove my down-vote and give you an up-vote. Yeah, I was being a stickler, but if we encourage the original poster to stick with null layouts and setBounds, he's going to create very ugly rigid, very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Use a layout manager to manage the sizing of your buttons, don't use `setBounds()`. You currently create one but don't set it and so its not used.

```
layout = new FlowLayout();
setLayout(null); // Why set null and not layout
```

Set the layout correctly and then you could can use a `char` in your for loop like

```
for(char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
    JButton button = new JButton("" + c);
    // add action listener also
    add(button); // adding will add it using the layout manager
}
```

You can learn more about [layout managers here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Yes, use an array or a collection such as either a simple array of JButton or a `List<JButton>` or its concrete implementation, an `ArrayList<JButton>`
- Yes, create your letter JButtons in a for loop as many have suggested.
- But don't create your special buttons there, buttons such as your reset button or your exit button.
- Create one AbstractAction or ActionListener class for all the letter buttons to share and a unique AbstractAction or ActionListener class for each special JButton
- Use layout managers, but not just one -- **nest** them. For instance, the overall GUI can use a BorderLayout with the drawing held BorderLayout.CENTER and the buttons in the SOUTH or PAGE_END position, the JPanels that hold your buttons could be held in a BoxLayout using JPanel, the letter buttons in a GridLayout using JPanel and the same for the specialty buttons.
- Use a separate JPanel for drawing the hangman image. Keep its logic separate from everything else. All it cares about is the number of wrong letters guessed, and then it should draw the appropriate images depending on this value. So I'd give it a public method for incrementing this number as well as a public method for resetting the number and its drawing.

For instance

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutFoo extends JPanel {

   // using a List of JButtons to hold my collection
   private List<JButton> letterButtons = new ArrayList<>();
   private DrawingPanel drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();

   public LayoutFoo() {
      JPanel letterButtonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0, 3, 3));
      letterButtonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Letters"));
      ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
      for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
         String text = String.valueOf(c);
         JButton button = new JButton(text);
         button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
         letterButtons.add(button); // add JButton to List<JButton>
         letterButtonPanel.add(button);  // and add to GridLayout-using JPanel
      }

      // JPanel to hold non-letter JButtons
      JPanel specialBtnsPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 3, 3));
      specialBtnsPanel.add(new JButton(new ResetAction("Reset", KeyEvent.VK_R)));
      specialBtnsPanel.add(new JButton(new ExitAction("Exit", KeyEvent.VK_X)));


      // JPanel to hold non-drawing JPanels. It uses BoxLayout
      JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
      bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
      bottomPanel.add(letterButtonPanel);
      bottomPanel.add(specialBtnsPanel);

      // set layout and border of main JPanel and add other JPanels to it
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3, 3, 3, 3));
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
      add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Button pressed: " + e.getActionCommand());
         ((AbstractButton) e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
      }
   }

   private class ResetAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ResetAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         for (JButton button : letterButtons) {
            button.setEnabled(true);
         }
      }
   }

   private class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ExitAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         Component component = (Component) e.getSource();
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(component);
         win.dispose();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LayoutFoo mainPanel = new LayoutFoo();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayoutFoo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 500;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private int wrongLetterCount = 0;

   public DrawingPanel() {
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Hang Man"));
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      // TODO: draw hangman here based on wrong letter count!
   }

   public void incrementWrongLetterCount() {
      wrongLetterCount++;
      repaint();
   }

   public void reset() {
      wrongLetterCount = 0;
      repaint();
   }
}
```